# Can you please help me with this error of main function not found? I am just a beginner at Java and I am stuck at this

Tags: exception

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/npBxo.png)**Can you please help? I am even new to stackoverflow, I am not able to embed my code. Can anybody please guide me through this. I have added the image of the error that I am encountering.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can just paste your code in  triple ticks like so and embed your code there -

````
``` ```
````

To answer your question, your error reads `Main method not found in class customcheckedexc` that's because when you run execute java with `java customcheckedexc` command you're specifying which class you want to execute and all Java applications begin execution by calling main( )

Ideally you should be compiling the class that contains your main function which in this case would be your voting class and then executing it.

Taken directly from the book mentioned below:
When Java source code is compiled, each individual class is put into its own output file
named after the class and using the .class extension. This is why it is a good idea to give
your Java source files the same name as the class they contain—the name of the source file
will match the name of the .class file. When you execute java as just shown, you are actually
specifying the name of the class that you want to execute. It will automatically search for
a file by that name that has the .class extension. If it finds the file, it will execute the code
contained in the specified class.

Also, you might to have a look at the [naming conventions](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html) used in Java.

P.S. Java™ The Complete Reference - this is a really good book for understanding Java.

Comment: Thank you so much. It was great blunder though from my side.

Comment: Happy to help! :)